# Can we use list comprehension to work on a variable outside the for loop used?

Tags: python

I just wanted to know if the list comprehension in python can be used to act on a variable that is outside the perview of the for loop iterating variable?

I have written this code to generate a list of vrf names

```
def generate_vrf_name(start_name,number):
    vrf_list = []
    for i in range(50):
        vrf_list.append('vrf member ' + vrf_name.split('-')[0] + '-' + str("{:03d}".format(int(vrf_name.split('-')[-1])+i)))
    return vrf_list

generate_vrf_name('V6-1',50)
```

This will return a list of vrf names. I thought of exploring the possibilities of using list comprehension here since I have a for statement and the output that i require is also a list. I have used list comprehension (basics) that works on the variables of for loop but haven;t tried writing using a variable outside the for loop in my list comprehension. is this do-able? if so can someone shed some light on this pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you expected:

```
def generate_vrf_name(vrf_name,number):
    return ['vrf member ' + vrf_name.split('-')[0] + '-' + str("{:03d}".format(int(vrf_name.split('-')[-1])+i)) for i in range(number)]

print(generate_vrf_name('V6-1',3))
```

Output:

```
['vrf member V6-001', 'vrf member V6-002', 'vrf member V6-003']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i expected. so in list comprehension, there is no rule that it will work only on the variables that is used for for loop iterations, instead we can access any other variables as well.. This helps in my understanding.. Thanks.